# Limit the Number of Posts in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, theming

I'd like to limit the number of posts of a custom post type to a maximum (e.g. 5 posts), regardless of the users.
For example, say i have my custom post type named CUSTOMPOSTS, if there are 5 of these posts, nobody should be able to create new ones (without first deleting one of the others).

Can it be done?

Kind regards!

Answer (score 0):

**There are multiple ways of doing it.** But the easiest is to hook into `wp_insert_post` and prevent it from working. You could force every new post to `draft` until they delete/unpublish an older one and when they do you can allow them to publish new one.